# Switch ServerAPI to "Apache 2.0 Handler" from "FastCGI" only for a single vhost

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to process a single virtual host alone in "Apache 2.0 Handler" mode (using mod_php5)?
I have a dedicated server which is configured to run PHP in FastCGI mode and I have a software which runs perfectly in other servers with ServerAPI in phpinfo() set to "Apache 2.0 Handler" but in this server it is set to "CGI/FastCGI"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to remove x-application handler from Apache's global config and add your handler's choice (AddHandler) only at ... blocks.

Comment: What you guys changed for changing server api to apache 2.0 handler. I am not able switch it to apache 2.0 handler from cgi/fastcgi. If possible then please ellaborate.